# Assignment of elements of several lists with tuple

Tags: python, list, tuples

I don't understand following behavior of lists assignment with tuple. I'm probably missing something evident...

Following code:

```
a, b = 1, 2
print(a, b)
```

produces that output:

```
1 2
```

as expected. **However, following code**:

```
list0, list1 = ([None] * 1, ) * 2
list0[0], list1[0] = 0, 1
print(list0)
print(list1)
```

has following output:

```
[1]
[1]
```

while I would expect

```
[0]
[1]
```

What am I missing? I'm using Python 3.7.

Comment: I'm not quite sure why this is happening but trying to assign the lists as a whole `list0, list1 = [0], [1]` seems to work as expected.

Comment: @meissner_ see duplicate question.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog thanks for pointing me to the duplicated question... with a detailed answer to understand the background of what happens.